# I want to change my navbar font and color

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view

The following is my scss file

```
div.navbar-collapse ul.navbar-nav li {
  color: #E69D32;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

This is my view file

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About Us", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", root_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

But the view is still the same. not changing color and font.

[image]

Comment: what is the question? You are already defining a color and font in your css. Do you want to change that, when, why?

Comment: it doesn't change. you can see in my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a class to your link_to, then style that class.

```
<%= link_to "Home", PATH, class: 'style_class' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style both div.navbar-collapse and ul.navbar-nav li, add a comma in between them, like so.

div.navbar-collapse, ul.navbar-nav li

If you want to style the child ul, do this.

div.navbar-collapse > ul.navbar-nav li

Comment: I tried both but it doesn't change ... because of Ruby tags ?

Answer (score 1):

You've `a` tags inside your `li` tags, so you need apply your styles to the `a` tag directly.

```
div.navbar-collapse ul.navbar-nav li {
  a {
    color: #E69D32;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```